# Radio Button List

Tags: php

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I'm using the code below to construct a list with a radio button as a way of selecting each row of data.

```
<?php

mysql_connect("hostname", "username", "password")or
die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database");



$result = mysql_query("SELECT userdetails.userid, finds.userid, finds.locationid, detectinglocations.locationid, detectinglocations.locationname, finds.dateoftrip, finds.findname, finds.finddescription FROM userdetails, finds, detectinglocations WHERE finds.userid=userdetails.userid AND finds.locationid=detectinglocations.locationid AND finds.userid = 1");
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
// table is empty
  echo 'There are currently no finds recorded for this location.';
echo"<table>\n";
  while (list($userid, $dateoftrip) =
    mysql_fetch_row($result))
  {

    echo"<tr>\n"
    .
     "<td><input type='radio' name='radio' dateoftrip, value='{$userid}' /></td>\n"
    ."<td><small>{$dateoftrip}</small><td>\n"
    ."</tr>\n";
  }
  echo"<tr><td colspan=\"3\">";
  echo"<br>";
  echo"</td></tr>";
  echo'</table>';

?>
```

I can manage to construct the list but the value next to the radio button is the 'userid' whereas I'm looking to put the 'dateoftrip' against each radio button.

I've been working on this for a while now and I can't see where my error is.

I just wondered whether someone could perhaps take a look at this please and let me know where I'm going wrong.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_row()` returns a numeric-indexed array from the result resource having fields in the same order as you selected them.  Since your `SELECT` list's first 2 fields are `userdetails.userid, finds.userid`, those are the two returned back to your `list()` call.

Instead, it's easier to use `mysql_fetch_assoc()`.  You could user `mysql_fetch_row()` and figure out the numeric indices of the two columns you need, but that's difficult.  In the best situation, you would only include the two columns you actually need in your `SELECT` in the first place, which would cause your code to work correctly.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $userid = $result['userid'];
  $dateoftrip = $result['dateoftrip'];
  // etc...
}
```

Note, that since you're fetching two columns called `userid` from different tables, you should create aliases for them to differentiate them after fetching:

```
// Aliases for userdetails.userid, finds.userid:
$result = mysql_query("SELECT userdetails.userid AS userid, finds.userid AS findsid, finds.locationid, detectinglocations.locationid, detectinglocations.locationname, finds.dateoftrip, finds.findname, finds.finddescription FROM userdetails, finds, detectinglocations WHERE finds.userid=userdetails.userid AND finds.locationid=detectinglocations.locationid AND finds.userid = 1");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in this line:

```
while (list($userid, $dateoftrip) =
```

given the query is:

```
SELECT userdetails.userid, finds.userid, finds.locationid, detectinglocations.locationid, detectinglocations.locationname, finds.dateoftrip, finds.findname, .....
```

list() assign the variable in order as returned by the SELECT query, the first two result columns are actually userid.

I suggest to use:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))   {
[...]
"<td><small>".$row["dateoftrip"]."</small></td>\n"  // you also have a typo here
```

or change your query to just return userid and dateoftrip in that order

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to reply to my post and the invaluable knowledge. Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting a lot more data than you are using. Try reducing your `SELECT` statement so that the first field selected is the user ID, and the second one is the date of trip. Then maybe you can hope that your `list` statement will work as you want it.

Comment: Hi many thanks for taking the time to reply to my post and for the guidance. It's really appreciated. Kind regards